# Rate limit identity server 4 token endpoint

Tags: asp.net, authentication, identityserver4, rate-limiting

There are some client APIs spamming our identity server 4 token endpoint (`/connect/token`). I was thinking to use the [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit) to limit the amount of allowed requests per IP. I have added a rule (both in General and IP rules) to limit requests to `/connect/token`.

The problem is that during testing with Postman, `AspNetCoreRateLimit` does not take `/connect/token` into account, thus it does not apply the rule. Postman was getting an access token with every new request even when it violated the rules.

What am I doing wrong? This is the right way to implement such functionality? Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Where in the pipeline are you registering the middleware? Is it before or after `app.UseIdentityServer()`?

Comment: That was the issue. `app.UseIpRateLimiting` should be BEFORE `app.UseIdentityServer`. thank you @mackie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trick is to register `app.UseIpRateLimiting();` BEFORE you register `app.UseIdentityServer();`.